# Where can I find gun stats?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Where can I find a good breakdown online of the various guns offered in Modern Warfare 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a fairly comprehensive list here : 
http://www.themodernwarfare3.com/mw3/weapons-list/

Including some info on the new weapon proficiency tuning options.

Comment: That's neat, I hadn't seen anything about the weapon proficiency tuning