# Modern Warfare 3: Weapon Damage Charts

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

As a man who plays a lot with numbers, I have often found unbelievable use out of call of duty weapon charts such as this one:

http://www.joinaclan.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/MW2-Weapon-Chart.gif

Does anyone have a link to the modern warfare 3 weapon chart?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34491/where-can-i-find-gun-stats

Comment: @Ian Sadly that really isn't what I'm looking for at all.  The chart I linked has actual damage used to calculate how many bullets it takes to drop a single target, the answer to that question shows a bar of 'power' that has no correlation to true damage

Comment: Gotcha; to my knowledge there's nothing official for that, so it will likely be some time before it comes out.

Comment: @Ian I think the other chart was made based off PC users opening the gun specs, it was the single most useful tool I've come across and I hope one shows up soon =D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an unofficial weapon stats chart:

[image]

Comment: What is "u bruh" and where can I get one?

Comment: @Broseph you're officially my favorite, my only regret is I have but one upvote.

Comment: Any chance there is a chart that shows magazine capacity if you are using the extra mags perk (its not really a perk, but in the same area as kick)?

Answer (score 3):

This graphic I recently found is less pretty, but contains additional info on launchers and headshot multiplier among other things.

[image: modernwarfare3maps weapon info graphic]