# What are the differences between the MW3 pistols:P99 and the Five Seven?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Which one has a better recoil? How many bullets does each clip hold? What can you attach to these weapons? Do the differences between these weapons make one better-suited for one situation compared to the other?

Answer (score 7):

The P99 holds fewer rounds (12 vs 16 for the Five-Seven) but does more damage per shot at close range (49 vs 36), although in practical terms this still means 3 body shots to kill a hostile with full life.  The P99 fires faster.  They both have the same attachments available.  (Silencer, Akimbo, Tac Knife, Extended Mags).  I don't have recoil statistics on them, but I believe they are both comparable.

The semi-auto clip-fed pistols are all pretty similar, so which one you choose is mostly a matter of personal preference.  You might switch between them to gain the experience bonuses at various levels of use, but otherwise there's not really a huge difference.

If you want to compare other weapons in MW3, the chart linked from this question:

[Modern Warfare 3: Weapon Damage Charts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34524/modern-warfare-3-weapon-damage-charts)

is the best data currently available.

Comment: @Jo'nathanTummins, if you've got an answer you like, click the check mark under the number of the left to "accept" it, which shows other people that the question is answered.