# Do silencers reduce damage in MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

A friend of mine says that silencers reduce damage in Modern Warfare 3?  I thought it only reduced the range.  Any truth to that?

Thanks.

Comment: In real life silencers don't reduce damage or range.

Comment: @TrilbyDax it's still fairly common for video games to reduce damage with a suppressor for balance reasons. No idea if MW3 falls in that camp though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in the chart in my answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34524/modern-warfare-3-weapon-damage-charts), range and damage are intertwined.  The silencer does reduce the range of the gun, and thus reduces the radius of "close range" damage.  This means that you will likely notice that it takes more shots to kill targets, unless they are very close to you.